# error: cannot find symbol for react native linkedin login

Tags: android, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using react-native-linkedin-login package for SSO signing, After all the configuration I am getting below error.
As per error, I imported package in packageList file but still it gives me a error.

```
android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
import com.linkedin.android.mobilesdk.RNLinkedinLoginPackage;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class RNLinkedinLoginPackage
  location: package com.linkedin.android.mobilesdk
``
```